# how to get the same result by using function and closure together in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to make the following(below) function call to give the same result in both situations:

```
sum(5,4);   // 9
sum(5)(4);   // this should also print 9
```

I tried the following but it's not working:

```
function sum(x,y){

   var a = x;
   var b = y;

   if (y == undefined && y == ''){
   return function (a,b){
      return a +b;
      }
   }
   else {
     return a +b;
   }

 }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: this `y == undefined && y == ''` can't be true

Comment: i dont get your question .. You mean sum(5)+sum(4) should also be 9 ? .. im confused

Comment: use if(typeof y == "undefined") instead

Comment: @DTH  I have to write a function that can be called either of the way, but, it should result the same both ways

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to `curry` your function for your requirement,

```
function sum(x,y){
  if(y === undefined){
    return function(y){ return x+y; }
  } else { 
      return x + y; 
  }
}

sum(5,4);   // 9
sum(5)(4);  // 9
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use logical `OR`(||), not `AND`(&&)

```
function sum(x,y){
   if (y == undefined || y == ''){
      return function (y){
        return x + y;
      }
   }
   else {
     return x + y;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The "cool" one line answer:

```
function sum(x, y){ 
   return y != undefined? x+y : function(a){return x + a}; 
}
```

Comment: yep, a little bit more, but still pretty simple in this case. It's funny tho. And I agree with your commentary, this functionnality is pretty useless to process a sum...

Answer (score 2):

**Careful: You probably won't need that functionality, it's simply redundant.**

You can use conditioning like that:

```
function sum( x , y ){
  if(y == undefined){
    return function( y ){
      return x + y;
    };
  }
  else{
    return x + y;
  }
}
```

Comment: `You probably won't need that functionality` So you are saying that function currying is an unnecessary feature with javascript?

Comment: No, it's just redundant to create a function that can be callable with both of these syntaxes. `func(5)(4);` can be more readable and flexible in some extends, but how is it beneficial to have two syntaxes?

Comment: That will be beneficial in customizing already existing function based on developer's context. refer this example https://jsfiddle.net/hqjtL6xL/

Comment: I **just** said that's not the problem? Conditioning to use both func(x,y) and func(x)(y) is redundant and OP should be advised to not use that.

Comment: @Roberto actually it was posted after the accepted answer, three minutes difference. Great minds think alike, but still, better be correct. :)

Comment: @Roberto Sha is right, i was writing mine just when the first one was posted.